# Chain Matrix Multiplication

Tags: algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

Im trying to learn chain matrix multiplication.

Suppose A is a 10 × 30 matrix, B is a 30 × 5 matrix, and C is a 5 × 60 matrix. Then,

How do we get  the following number of operations? (Is it number of rows into columns ???)

```
(AB)C = (10×30×5) + (10×5×60) = 1500 + 3000 = 4500 operations
A(BC) = (30×5×60) + (10×30×60) = 9000 + 18000 = 27000 operations.
```

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-8-matrix-chain-multiplication/

Comment: Multiplying a M x N matrix A and and N X P matrix B (to get D say) involves computing each of the M x P elements of D, and the computation of each element of D is a dot product of a row of A -- an N element vector -- with a column of B -- another N element vector. So there are M*P*N operations in all.

Answer (score 1):

The number of operations is the number of multiplications required to calculate the result. `A * B` will result in a 10 x 5 matrix. Each entry in this matrix is the dotproduct of the respective row of `A` with the column of `B` with the same index. Thus: `A * B` requires calculation of 10 x 5 cells, where each cell is the sum of 30 multiplication, so 10 x 5 x 30. Though this is a rather strange representation.